# Playing a short sound in quick succession using MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have an app where I have to make a sound fairly often in succession.  I'm using MediaPlayer, but keep running into these issues.

I'm initializing the MediaPlayer like this, which doesn't seem to be a problem:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.mysound);
```

At first, I simply tried calling `mp.start();` whenever I need to play the sound.  However, if I do that and try playing it in quick succession (via a button), it only plays it every 3-4 tries when it needs to be every time.  Since there was no error, I figured it was already "playing". So I added code to check if it was playing and if so, called mp.stop() before calling start() again.

```
if (mp.isPlaying()) {
  mp.stop();
}
mp.start();
```

But then I get an error, `start called in state #`.  So then I tried adding `mp.setOnPreparedListener(this)`, overriding `onPrepared` and calling `mp.prepareAsync()` before calling `mp.start()`.  However I keep getting errors about start called in state #.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?  Or is there a better way?

Comment: Have you looked into [SoundPool](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool)? Unless your sound is very long, I think `SoundPool` might be better suited for what you're trying to do. Among other things, it preloads sounds into buffers, and therefore is very responsive, and you don't have to deal with different states (preparing, playing, etc.). Playing sounds quickly in succession should be no problem, and sounds can overlap as well (up to a channel limit you supply). In any case, that would be my recommendation.